# Функция MM_openBrWindow

Tags: javascript

JavaScript:   `MM_openBrWindow`

Я новичек в этом, мне нужно узнать инфу, зачем эта функция? Что она делает?

Нашел её, когда сайт на своих страницах размещает контекст с других страниц, при этом в строке всё красиво, как будто это родное.

Мне нужно сделать похожее, часть страницы копируется с другого сайта.

P.S. Инфа, которая копируется, обновляется раз в три недели, могу ли я автоматизировать процесс, чтобы не прописывать всё заново (картинки, текст и т.д.)?

С уважением Олег М

Answer (score 1):

Разве это стандартная функция JavaScript? Посмотрите исходники скриптов, наверняка вы найдете тело этой функции. Чаще всего это что-то подобное

```
function MM_openBrWindow(url, name, features) {
     window.open(url, name, features);
     return false;
}
```

То есть просто обертка над методом open, который создает новое окно обозревателя, аналогично команде "Новое окно" в меню.

Если вы хотите показывать информацию с другого сайт внутри своего, то для этого вполне подходят фреймы, тогда и обновлять ничего не надо.